# Chrome Upgrade (v80) and Angular ViewEncapsulation.Native vs ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

Tags: angular, google-chrome, shadow-dom, angular2viewencapsulation

With the latest version of `Chrome Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)` my Angular application has suddenly stopped to work. On troubleshooting the issue found the error "createShadowRoot is not a function" in the console logs.

In several Angular components in our application, we have used ViewEncapsulation strategy Native as below

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`

It seems that the with the latest version of Chrome, support for Shadow Dom v0 is removed as [documented](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4507242028072960) (snip below)

[image]

It seems the solution is to replace the ViewEncapsulation strategy from Native to ShadowDom like the below

```
//encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
```

**Question:**

After changing the ViewEncapsulation strategy, my application started to work . The question is,

- Is ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom a drop in replacement for ViewEncapsulation.Native ? (shadow DOM v0 vs v1)
- Apart of the changing the ViewEncapsulation strategy, anything else I need to change / check?
- What other impacts should I check in my application to ensure that my application works seamlessly
- Any other risks that we should anticipate?

**Note** : My application is only supported on Google Chrome.